# Do I include the open source copyright notice in an enterprise software (for commercial use)?

Tags: licensing, open-source, bsd-license

I have included OpenCV libraries in the enterprise software written in c++. I know that OpenCV is a BSD 3-Clause license, which means most of its libraries are free to use, modified, and redistribute. And all the libraries I used in the enterprise software are free (did not useSIFT or SURF). What are the actual texts and files I should include in my project in order to meet the license compliance rulse?

Do I have to include OpenCV license in my project?

Do I need to include a licence notice in all the header/cpp files or only the header files that include opencv2.hpp?

Thanks in advance for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

The license itself gives you your answer.

> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

So yes, you must include the license text in your docs, or put it in the about box, or similar.

Comment: Does this mean that I should display the license somewhere in the UI of the program so that the users can read it?

Comment: Also, For the first line _1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer._ Does that mean I should attach the notice within the header and cpp files that utilized the libraries?

Comment: @caoscarlett: honestly, if you aren't confident in what you need to do to meet the terms of such a straightforward, simple license, you better get a lawyer now.